# Mod Rewrite - Simple Question

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my current .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /product/

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ ./$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^contact/?$ ./contact.php [QSA,L]
```

Everything is working fine now..

- /product/contact return to /product/contact/
- /product/contact.php return to /product/contact/

**Question..**

- How to make all my .php will be /contact/ /help/ /faq/
- Now I should to add contact.php help.php faq.php to the htaccess
- I tried to add RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [QSA,L] but it will be return loop.

Let me know how to fix it ;)

Comment: Maybe it's just because you were trying to solve the problem already, but the bottom line of your .htaccess already redirects /product/help/ to /product/help.php, is that on purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly to do this in your rewrite statements will make an infinite loop, since Apache will try to rewrite `help/` to `help.php`, and then `help.php` to `help/` etc etc.

If it's really necessary, do it in your application (example in PHP):

```
<?php 
// The (\?.*)? so it "ignores" query strings
if (preg_match('/\.php(\?.*)?$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
  header('Location: ' . str_replace('.php', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Escape the dot in the regular expression. Otherwise you will get an infinite loop if the URI path just ends in a `php` like in `foo-php` or `bar/php`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that this line is backwards?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

As I understand it, this rewrites domain.com/product/help/ to domain.com/product/help.php.
Try

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).php $1/ [L,QSA]
```

This should rewrite domain.com/product/help.php to domain.com/product/help/
and domain.com/foobar/baz.php to domain.com/foobar/baz/
etc.